# How to avoid any type and use appropriate type in playwright fixture

Tags: typescript, types, playwright, fixtures

I want to replace any with the appropriate type

```
export const discountsTest = baseTest.extend<{
  discount: Serializable;
  discountOpts: any;
}>({
  discount: [
    async ({ discountOpts }, use) => {
      const discountApi = new api(adminToken);
      const discount = await discountApi.createDiscount(discountOpts);
      expect(discount._status).toBe("OK");
      await use(discount);
    },
    { auto: true },
  ],
  discountOpts: [
    async ({ a }, use) => {
      await use(a);
    },
  ],
});
```

I tried replacing any with `Record<string,unknown>` but got an error in the `discountOpts` and in the parameter a fixture saying

[image]

```
Type '[({ a }: { discount: Serializable; discountOpts: Record<string, unknown>; } & PlaywrightTestArgs & PlaywrightTestOptions & pages & PlaywrightWorkerArgs & PlaywrightWorkerOptions, use: (r: Record<...>) => Promise<...>) => Promise<...>]' is not assignable to type 'TestFixtureValue<Record<string, unknown>, { discount: Serializable; discountOpts: Record<string, unknown>; } & PlaywrightTestArgs & PlaywrightTestOptions & pages & PlaywrightWorkerArgs & PlaywrightWorkerOptions> | [...]'.
  Type '[({ a }: { discount: Serializable; discountOpts: Record<string, unknown>; } & PlaywrightTestArgs & PlaywrightTestOptions & pages & PlaywrightWorkerArgs & PlaywrightWorkerOptions, use: (r: Record<...>) => Promise<...>) => Promise<...>]' is not assignable to type 'TestFixture<Record<string, unknown>, { discount: Serializable; discountOpts: Record<string, unknown>; } & PlaywrightTestArgs & PlaywrightTestOptions & pages & PlaywrightWorkerArgs & PlaywrightWorkerOptions>'.
    Type '[({ a }: { discount: Serializable; discountOpts: Record<string, unknown>; } & PlaywrightTestArgs & PlaywrightTestOptions & pages & PlaywrightWorkerArgs & PlaywrightWorkerOptions, use: (r: Record<...>) => Promise<...>) => Promise<...>]' provides no match for the signature '(args: { discount: Serializable; discountOpts: Record<string, unknown>; } & PlaywrightTestArgs & PlaywrightTestOptions & pages & PlaywrightWorkerArgs & PlaywrightWorkerOptions, use: (r: Record<...>) => Promise<...>, testInfo: TestInfo): any'.ts(2322)
discount.fx.ts(10, 3): The expected type comes from property 'discountOpts' which is declared here on type 'Fixtures<{ discount: Serializable; discountOpts: Record<string, unknown>; }, {}, PlaywrightTestArgs & PlaywrightTestOptions & pages, PlaywrightWorkerArgs & PlaywrightWorkerOptions>'
```

[image]

I'm expecting to replace any with appropriate type. I type of this `disocuntOpts` is string or number or both string and number.

Comment: did you try `unknown` instead of `any`? The optimal solution would be define a type or an interface that would describe the structure of `discountOpts`.

Comment: with unknown it works fine but is it the good way of using it?

Comment: `unknown` type is used when we don't know what type of data will be returned as a result of the operation (e.g it could be either boolean or string or number)